# Problem in libassimp-dev is preventing me using apt-get

Tags: apt

I have a package conflict. It seems like no matter what I do I can not remove the offending package. `apt-get` acts like it wont actually remove a package until all dependencies are resolved. But I can't resolve dependencies because of the conflict.

```
john@john-GA-880GMA-USB3:~$ sudo apt-get -f purge assimp-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-assimp : Depends: assimp-dev but it is not going to be installed
 ros-fuerte-robot-model : Depends: libassimp-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I try apt-get -f install and receive the error:

```
sudo apt-get -f installReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libassimp-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libassimp-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/88.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 470 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 358595 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libassimp-dev (from .../libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/assimp/aiAnim.h', which is also in package assimp-dev 2.0.0.7-ubuntu1~oneiric1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libassimp-dev_2.0.863+dfsg-2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: And the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like two packages, libassimp-dev and assimp-dev, are providing the exact same file, which has caused a conflict.

From their package names, I assume that they are duplicates of the same thing.

The key line from this is the following one:

> dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/**libassimp-dev**_2.0.863+dfsg-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
>    trying to overwrite '/usr/include/assimp/aiAnim.h', which is also in package **assimp-dev** 2.0.0.7-ubuntu1~oneiric1

(I added the bolding)

[I found this thread about someone else having the same issue](http://answers.ros.org/question/35630/broken-dependencies-in-fuerte-on-ubuntu-1204/) and the answers there give some advice.

If I were you, I'd first check to see whether `sudo aptitude purge libassimp-dev` helps - if it works, then it'll offer you a few different ways to solve the conflict from the first part of your question.

**Note** if you go down the `dpkg -i --force-overwrite` route, you want to apply the fix for libassimp-dev only, not the one for yaml-cpp as you are not actually experiencing that one.

Comment: The link was very helpful. Turns out ros-fuetre has some dependency issues. I had to first remove fuerte, then remove/reinstall yaml-cpp and libassimp-dev, then re-install fuerte.